# How should I change my compiler setting to use Variable name with foreign language

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-construction

I've been only using English while naming any variables or functions.

But my client wants me to name all the variables in Korean.

I figured out naming variables in Korean is allowed in visual studio 2017 but not in visual studio code.

Is it possible to make visual studio code allow this as well?

Please see my errors below.[image]

[image]

And My Setting in VSCode

c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/*",

            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.16299.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.12.25827/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "C:/Users/lich_/GoogleDrive/MATLAB/HyoSeong_MATLAB_GUIImplementation/HITS_Hyosung/181031_HITS/C++Script/main.exe",
            ///input your file name including path.
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/gdb.exe",
            // minGW debugger path
            "preLaunchTask": "echo",
            // Enter your task name and first you build(your pretask, ) and debug
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "echo",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args" : [
                "-g", "C++Script/main.cpp",
                "-o", "C++Script/main.exe"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Has this question really have to do with text editors? It seems to be related to using different C++ compilers (Visual Studio and gcc).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I do totally agree with you.
Do you know how to change it's compiler ?

Comment: No, I don't, I use VSCode for entirely different technologies. How did you configure it in the first place? (Side note, you may want to edit the question and add tags for the appropriate language so you have a better chance to get help.)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thank you for your advice, I changed

Comment: The text file is encoded in utf8 with a BOM, pretty normal.  G++ tells you that it doesn't like the BOM.  That's a problem that was fixed a decade ago, check if you used the --finput-charset option.

Comment: Gcc doesn't allow non-ascii characters in the representation of a variable name (as of v9). You can use UCNs but that's probably not what your client wants. Clang is OK with non-ascii characters in source code , so if you can change to clang, it should be fine. Otherwise, i think you're out of options.